# Passing Image*[3] to const Image*[3] cannot be done with const_cast<Image*[3]>, alternatives?

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, constants

I have a function that takes in an array of pointers to images that will not be modified, defined as:

```
void processImg( const Image *myImgs[NUM_IMAGES] );
```

I'd like to pass in a non-`const` type.  I would expect to need to do this, but it is illegal (VS2010 says not allowed):

```
Image *imgsToProcess[NUM_IMAGES];
// ...fill in imgsToProcess

processImg( const_cast<Image*[NUM_IMAGES]>(imgsToProcess) );
```

I also tried:

```
processImg( const_cast<Image*[]>(imgsToProcess) ); //'const_cast' : cannot convert from 'Image *[3]' to 'Image *[]'
processImg( const_cast<Image**>(imgsToProcess) ); //'processImg' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Image **' to 'const Image *[]'
```

So then I changed the function and array definitions and did:

```
void processImg( const Image **myImgs, int numImages );
...
Image **imgsToProcess;
// ...fill in imgsToProcess

processImg( const_cast<Image**>(imgsToProcess), NUM_IMAGES );
```

To my surprise I still got this error message:

```
'processImg' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Image **' to 'const Image **'
```

What am I doing wrong, and is it possible to have a definition like my first one with `const Image *myImgs[NUM_IMAGES]` to accomplish this?

Comment: Are the pointers modified by the function? If not, make them `const`: `const Image * const myImgs[NUM_IMAGES]`. Don't count on `myImgs` having a particular number of elements, either. As far as the function is concerned, it's a pointer. Use `std::array` for something that knows its size.

Comment: Good point on the extra const. I will be checking that `NUM_IMAGES` elements are non-NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
    processImg(const_cast<const Image **>(imgsToProcess));
```

The problem is essentially that your `const_cast` is not casting to a `const`.

Comment: Ooof course... Is there no way to do it with this definition of processImg?
`void processImg( const Image *myImgs[NUM_IMAGES] );`

Answer (score 2):

You may have expected [const_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) to cast your object into a `const` version of the type you passed to it. But that's not how `const_cast` works.
Instead, you need to specify the **exact type** the object should be cast into.

So if you want

```
Image **
```

to be cast to

```
const Image **
```

write it as

```
const_cast<const Image**>(imgsToProcess);
```